# How to tell if any entities in context are dirty with .Net Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I want to be able to tell if there is any unsaved data in an entity framework context. I have figured out how to use the ObjectStateManager to check the states of existing entities, but there are two issues I have with this.

1. I would prefer a single function to call to see if any entities are unsaved instead of looping though all entities in the context.
2. I can't figure out how to detect entities I have added. This suggests to me that I do not fully understand how the entity context works. For example, if I have the ObjectSet myContext.Employees, and I add a new employee to this set (with .AddObject), I do not see the new entity when I look at the ObjectSet and I also don't see the .Count increase. However, when I do a context.SaveChanges(), my new entity is persisted...huh?

I have been unable to find an answer to this in my msdn searches, so I was hoping someone here would be able to clue me in.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var addedStateEntries = Context
    .ObjectStateManager
    .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added);
```

Comment: Ok, that looks like the answer. I am still a bit confused as to why the ObjectSet myContext.Employees does not contain the entity I just added.

Comment: Because `ObjectSet`s are queries, not collections.

Comment: Ok, we're getting to my misunderstanding of what those ObjectSets are supposed to be. So, is it correct to say that those ObjectSets are just the database state of the entities? If that is true, is there a collection that, for example, has all the Employee entities that are in memory (not just those in the database)?

Comment: I'll rephrase that. Is there a collection somewhere that has all the Employee entities that are in the context as opposed to just those that exist in the database?

Comment: I've started a new question on that topic at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716359/help-me-understand-entity-framework-contexts-please

Answer (score 9):

Via extension method (for every ObjectContext):

```
internal static class ObjectContextExtensions
{
    public static bool IsContextDirty(this ObjectContext objectContext)
    {
        return objectContext
            .ObjectStateManager
            .GetObjectStateEntries(
                EntityState.Added | 
                EntityState.Deleted | 
                EntityState.Modified).Any();
    }
}
```

or via partial method (only for your ObjectContext):

```
partial class MyModel
{
    public bool IsContextDirty()
    {
        return ObjectStateManager
            .GetObjectStateEntries(
                EntityState.Added | 
                EntityState.Deleted |
                EntityState.Modified).Any();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple way to get a reusable single method/property you could add a new method to your ObjectContext by creating a partial class and adding a property like this:

```
public partial class MyEntityContext
{
  public bool IsContextDirty
  {
    get
    {
      var items = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added);
      if(items.Any())
        return true;
      items = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Deleted);
      if (items.Any())
        return true;
      items = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified);
      if(items.Any())
        return true;
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Depending on what your looking for you could expose other properties to know if there are just deletes or modifications.  This method could be simplified, but I wanted it to be clear what you would need to do.

Comment: Post updated. Never use `Count() > 0` instead of `Any()`, `Count()` iterates thru the whole collection to get the number, `Any()` will return true on first iteration.

Comment: Also, `GetObjectStateEntries` is never supposed to return `null`.