# How should I listen for entities being added/deleted from an ObjectContext?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, repository-pattern

As far as I can tell, [`ObjectContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx) doesn't expose any direct way of listening for items being added/removed. You *could* hook up to the [`SavingChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx) event, and query the [`ObjectStateManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectstatemanager.aspx) for which items have been added or removed. But this has several problems:

- The notification will occur before the items are actually added to the context.
- The notification will occur any time *any* changes are saved (even if no items are added/removed).
- It doesn't appear to be how [`SavingChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx) was intended to be used--it is more for validating data than notifying of changes.
- This is subjective, but it just *feels* wrong to me.

I've worked around this by implementing a limited version of the Repository Pattern--it handles creates, reads, and deletions, but updates are still performed by directly manipulating the properties of the entities themselves (and then saving changes from my repository).

I'm slightly uneasy about this for a few reasons:

- I thought [`ObjectContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx) was supposed to replace the repository from the repository pattern. It feels like I am duplicating work that the Entity Framework should be doing for me.
- Using an incomplete version of the Repository Pattern (the C, R, and D from CRUD) seems a little strange. Shouldn't a repository either be used for all 4 CRUD operations, or none?
- There must be a reason that the Entity Framework doesn't support add/delete notifications. By choosing to implement them anyway, am I creating a design headache that the Entity Framework developers chose to avoid?

For reference, here is a rough outline of my repository:

```
public class EntityArgs<T> : EventArgs
    where T : EntityObject
{
    ....

    public T Entity
    {
        get { return this.entity; }
    }
}

public delegate void EntityEventHandler<T>(object sender, EntityArgs<T> args) where T: EntityObject;

public class EntityRepository
{
    public event EntityEventHandler<Foo> FooAdded;
    public event EntityEventHandler<Foo> FooDeleted;

    ...

    public EntityRepository()
    {
        this.entities = new Entities();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos
    {
        get { return this.entities.Foos; }
    }

    public void AddFoo(Foo foo)
    {
        this.entities.Foos.AddObject(foo);
        this.entities.SaveChanges();
        this.OnFooAdded(foo);
    }

    public void DeleteFoo(Foo foo)
    {
        this.entities.Foos.DeleteObject(foo);
        this.entities.SaveChanges();
        this.OnFooDeleted(foo);
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        this.entities.SaveChanges();
    }

    ...
}
```

I'm quite new to the Entity Framework, so let me know if my approach is totally wrong.

EDIT: In response to Erix's suggestion to use `ObjectStateManager`, it *almost* addresses my issue, but not quite. The problem is that I want to be notified when `entities.Foos` will have the changes reflected in it. `ObjectStateManager.ObjectStateManagerChanged` occurs when `AddObject` is called, but before `SaveChanges` is called. So:

```
entities.ObjectStateManager.ObjectStateManagerChanged += (s, e) =>
    Console.WriteLine("Action: {0}, Object: {1}, Count: {2}", e.Action, e.Element, entities.Foos.Count());
var foo = ...
Console.WriteLine("Count: {0}", entities.Foos.Count());
entities.Foos.AddObject(foo);
entities.Foos.SaveChanged();
Console.WriteLine("Count: {0}", entities.Foos.Count());

// Output:
// Count: 0
// Action: Add, Object: ..., Count: 0
// Count: 1
```

Comment: What events are you interested in and why? A object being added/removed from the context, or a record being inserted or deleted from the database?

Comment: @ProgrammingHero: An object being added/removed from the context.

Comment: @ProgrammingHero: As for why, I am interested for a variety of reasons. One simple example would be so that I can know when to update a displayed list of entities meeting some criteria.

Comment: It is still not clear what you are looking for. Your comments and your edited questions looks like being in contrary.

Comment: Your question reminded me of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714857/how-to-tell-if-any-entities-in-context-are-dirty-with-net-entity-framework-4-0 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716359/help-me-understand-entity-framework-contexts-please

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the `ObjectStateManager`?
It should raise the event after the object is added.

shown here in MSDN, it looks like the correct way to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705449.aspx

Comment: This is almost what I need, but not quite. See my edit to my original question.