# Detailed state of object in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

How can I get the state only for property of an entity not for the entity?

Let us say I have an object from product class and only its price value has been changed so I want to now that:

1. ProductName Unchanged
2. ProductPrice Modified

It's easy to know that the object has been changed but I want to know the exact properties that have been changed.

How could I do this?

Comment: Seems like a dupe of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714857/how-to-tell-if-any-entities-in-context-are-dirty-with-net-entity-framework-4-0)

Comment: no Its not the same question!!!

Comment: Take a look at the link in the bottom-most answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ObjectStateEntry to call the GetModifiedProperties method like so (this has more sample than you need but have a look at GetModifiedProperties in the code below):

```
int orderId = 43680;

using (AdventureWorksEntities context =
    new AdventureWorksEntities())
{
    var order = (from o in context.SalesOrderHeaders
                 where o.SalesOrderID == orderId
                 select o).First();

    // Get ObjectStateEntry from EntityKey.
    ObjectStateEntry stateEntry =
        context.ObjectStateManager
        .GetObjectStateEntry(((IEntityWithKey)order).EntityKey);

    //Get the current value of SalesOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderNumber.
    CurrentValueRecord rec1 = stateEntry.CurrentValues;
    string oldPurchaseOrderNumber =
        (string)rec1.GetValue(rec1.GetOrdinal("PurchaseOrderNumber"));

    //Change the value.
    order.PurchaseOrderNumber = "12345";
    string newPurchaseOrderNumber =
        (string)rec1.GetValue(rec1.GetOrdinal("PurchaseOrderNumber"));

    // Get the modified properties.
    IEnumerable<string> modifiedFields = stateEntry.GetModifiedProperties();
    foreach (string s in modifiedFields)
        Console.WriteLine("Modified field name: {0}\n Old Value: {1}\n New Value: {2}",
            s, oldPurchaseOrderNumber, newPurchaseOrderNumber);

    // Get the Entity that is associated with this ObjectStateEntry.
    SalesOrderHeader associatedEnity = (SalesOrderHeader)stateEntry.Entity;
    Console.WriteLine("Associated Enity's ID: {0}", associatedEnity.SalesOrderID);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look around the interwebs, I found [this article](http://harmneervens.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-find-dirty-property-in-entity.html) that speaks to exactly what you want to do.