# make a single PC application work on the network

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, networking, windows-7

I have a working WPF application that uses EntityFramework 6.0 to connect to a SQL Server database. Below is how my source code is structured.

[image: Solution Explorer - Part 1]

[image: Solution Explorer - Part 2]

TestPacks.Data contains the model of the database and logic to interact with the database. While TestPacks.Entities contains the mapped entities.

Now, I need to make this Application work on the local network so that multiple users can see the same data simultanously.

Here is how I plan to go ahead.
a) install the database on a server machine
b) change the below connection string to reference the database from the server instead of the local machine.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestPacksContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TestPacksModel.csdl|res://*/TestPacksModel.ssdl|res://*/TestPacksModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=WASIM-DELL;initial catalog=TPM;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Is there anything else I will require to do for my application to work correctly? My requirements says that about 10-25 people (max) might work on the application over the network.

Please suggest.

Comment: As long as there's nothing in the design and implementation of the code itself that would preclude multi-user database access, this should be all you need to do.

Comment: How does you code handle you reading a value, somone else changes the value, then you try to change a value. EF may or may not throw a exception on you depending on how you set up your database.

Comment: thats a good point. I wanted suggestions on this? All I am doing is using the DBContext to read the values, nothing else. So while reading the values, if a different user changes the same thing, there will be issues. What is the way to get around that? Also, what about performance.? is there any special measure i need to take if there are 25 users lets say

Answer (score 0):

You need to do concurrency check, Refer this sites [Entity Framework Update check if the record has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503797/entity-framework-update-check-if-the-record-has-changed)  "http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application"