# Keep DbContext open for DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, savechanges

I have a DataGridView and the DataGridView's DataSource is a BindingList I got from the Entity Framework (V6) via context.Person.Local.ToBindingList().
After I set the DataSource to this BindingList, I dispose the context, because I read that keeping the context open would be bad practice.

So, if I wanted to add a new row, I would click on the "add" button that comes with the BindingNavigator that got created when I dragged the "people" object data source to my Windows Form.
Every time I click the "add" button, I get an exception that tells me that the context has been disposed.
Do I need to keep the context open all the time when using DataGridView? Oh and: the DataSource might change during runtime depending on the selection of a ListBox Item.

Also, when the context has been disposed and I edited one row from the DataGridView, how could I find out (after multiple changes) which row has changed?
I tried to do:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in peopleDataGridView.Rows)
{
    People item = (People)row.DataBoundItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        db.People.Attach(item);
    }
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

...but SaveChanges() did not recognize any changes. However, if I force every attached item to a "modified" state, it works. But I do not want to change 100 items to "modified", if only one got actually modified.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**
Oh well, so I changed my code to keep the context open all the time (or at least as long as the form gets displayed).
Now, I ran into a different problem (people may have many jobs):

```
private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    People p = (People)listBox1.SelectedItem;
    if(p != null)
    {
        //jobBindingSource.Clear(); this caused another error at runtime...
        db.Entry(p).Collection(b => b.Job).Load();
        jobBindingSource.DataSource = db.Job.Local.ToBindingList();
    }
}
```

The DataGridView that is bound to this jobBindingSource instance shows the correct jobs for a person, but *in addition* to the jobs from the previously selected person. I tried to Clear() the entries, but if I do this and click on the same person twice, the datagridview starts to sometimes show no entries at all. A strange behaviour.
What am I doing wrong now?

**EDIT 2**
Okay... I found a solution myself. But I refuse to accept that this is the correct way to do it:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    People p = (People)listBox1.SelectedItem;
    if(p != null)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        db = new PeopleJobsEntities();
        db.People.Attach(p);
        db.Entry(p).Collection(person => person.Job).Load();
        jobBindingSource.DataSource = db.Job.Local.ToBindingList();
    }
}
```

Only if I dispose the context and open it anew, the whole thing works. The reason is that if I clear the local cache (of db.Job.Local), its entries will not be reloaded again even if I use the Load() method. Is there some way to force the reloading of entities?

Comment: Why dont you implement this process after any row is edited or changed otherwise you need to check all datagridview row by row to see which of them changed

Comment: this answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/11520100/8175473

Comment: @hsnbl I did not consider this because I hoped that EF would do this automatically for me. But only if I keep the context opened, this automation works :-(

Comment: Please don't change a question's scope after posting it. It disqualifies answers already given and it becomes utterly unclear what your actual problem is.

Comment: Am I really supposed to post a new question every time the problem slightly changes? Well ok... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I try not to keep the DBContext open for a long period of time, with datagrids you don't have much choice.  I set my grid's `DataSource` property to `IQueryable<T>` and then all the edits, deletes and additions are taken care of by the grid and context itself.  You just have to call `dbContext.SubmitChanges()` whenever you want to persist the changes.  You can save each time a user leaves a row by saving on the `RowLeave` or the `RowValidated` event.  Or you can save when you close the form.  But also make sure you call `dbContext.Dispose()` when you close the form as well.

To find out which rows change you can view the `ChangeSet` that is returned by doing the following:

```
var changes = dbContext.GetChangeSet();
dbContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks @jaredbaszler for your answer. But this worries me a bit: if I have a software that uses the DataGridView and if this software uses it in a window that is permanently open (i.e. because it is located on the software's main screen), then this software would be 'bad'?

Comment: It wouldn't be considered bad as long as you are disposing the DBContext when you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

- Be sure if your item is not null.
- Check your connection string.

And, try this :

```
db.People.Add(item);
```

Instead of :

```
db.People.Attach(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to @jaredbaszler I came up with this solution that works fine for me.
I decided to keep the DbContext alive all the time. To clear the local cache, I detached every entity inside in a loop. I think this is a very disgusting way to do it. There **must** be a better way...

This is what I have:

```
PeopleJobsEntities db;

public FormTest()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    db = new PeopleJobsEntities();
    db.Database.Log = Console.Write;
    db.People.Load();
    List<People> peoplelist = db.People.Local.ToList();
    listBox1.DataSource = peoplelist;
}

private void FormTest_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   if (db != null)
        db.Dispose();

}

private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    People p = (People)listBox1.SelectedItem;
    if(p != null)
    {
        List<Job> oldlist = db.Job.Local.ToList();
        foreach (Job j in oldlist)
        {
            db.Entry(j).State = EntityState.Detached;
        }
        db.Entry(p).Collection(b => b.Job).Load();
        jobBindingSource.DataSource = db.Job.Local.ToBindingList();
    }
}

private void jobBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in jobDataGridView.Rows)
    {
        if(row != null && row.DataBoundItem != null)
        {
            Job j = (Job)row.DataBoundItem;
            if(db.Entry(j).State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                if(j.People.Count == 0)
                {
                    People people = (People)listBox1.SelectedItem;
                    if (people != null)
                        j.People.Add(people);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

- Editing entries works
- Adding new entries works
- Deleting entries works